# How to find number of occurences of string in comma separated values field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field that contains comma separated values.
I found I can verify the presence in the list of "b" using this code:

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET('b','a,b,c,d,b,b')
```

I want a different thing:

**I want to find the number of occurrences of 'b' in that comma separated list**. Is this possible in MySQL? Or I must demand it to `array_count_values` in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

This blog post seems to do what you want:

http://nostylesheets.com/2009/07/17/mysql-substr-count/

Basically, it looks at the string length of the field, removes your target sub-string, then looks at the new length. If you know your substring was 4 characters long, and your new string is now 8 characters shorter than it was, then you know you had 2 occurrences.

Comment: I haven't red it still: but I can't eventually modify the field.

Comment: Sure you can. Use the REPLACE( ) function to insert new values, or replace current values with new ones.

Comment: What I wanted to say (sorry for my English) is that the field must remain the same as it was before: being this a SELECT, I'm sure the field remains the same after the calculations.

Comment: This approach will only tell you how many occurrences there are. It will not modify the data at all.

Answer (score 0):

LOCATE should do the trick.  Note that there are two different signatures - the first (two args) is to be called initially, then call the second (three args), giving the result of the first, as the third argument to the second.  More info at:

> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate
>
> LOCATE(substr,str), LOCATE(substr,str,pos)
>
> The first syntax returns the position of the first occurrence of
>   substring substr in string str. The second syntax returns the position
>   of the first occurrence of substring substr in string str, starting at
>   position pos. Returns 0 if substr is not in str.

Comment: By reading that text (I red) I understand you search the first time starting from 0, the second from the result of the first. But what if I have 50 occurrences? Or am I missing something really important?   :-)

Comment: keep calling it until it returns 0.